# How to pull stock indexes in a Java-based Selenium API twice a day?

Tags: java, jquery, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have a Selenium code working that auto connects to the CNBC markets page (https://www.cnbc.com/us-markets/). I had previously looked into getting this program working with Jsoup, but it turns out that the site is updated in realtime and the best way to pull this data is either to pull a JSON file or to use Selenium (as I understand it). Given that I've programmed Selenium to remote connect to the site, I'd like to know how to go about querying a stock on the page. I'd prefer to avoid learning a bunch of Javascript to make this happen, but I'm open to it if there's no other practical approach. I wonder if JQuery is the best tool?

Here's my code I have:

```
//Built in Java 1.7 due to Selenium compatabilities

//Import packages
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Point Selenium to Chrome Drive file
     File file = new File("C:\\Users\\zrr81\\eclipse-workspace\\WebScraper\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

     //Initialize Chrome driver and choose site
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the url you would like to connect to: ");
     String url = input.nextLine();

     //Try to connect, include catch for typos/errors
     try {
         driver.get(url);

     }
     catch(InvalidArgumentException e) {
         System.out.println("He's dead Jim! :/");
     }
     input.close();
}
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, I need to query a stock share price based on user input for the ticker (e.g. if the user inputs DJIA I need to pull the stock price for Dow Jones)

Comment: can you a little bit explain what you want exactly on  that website?

Comment: @hamidreza75 I need to query a stock share price based on user input for the ticker. I'll clarify this on an edit to the question too.